# Can I use variables in the prompt of the python raw_input function?

Tags: python, raw-input

`raw_input()` in python to get console input

In python's function `raw_input(' ')`, can I put variables between single quotes?

For example

```
K = 'cat'
F = 'fish'
```

If I want to prompt "Cat eat fish", how should I write it?

The following wording should be wrong：

```
raw_input('K eat F')
```

Is there any way to introduce variables into the raw_input function?

If the `raw_input` function is unable to implement this function, is there any other function to achieve this function, i.e. to get the console input, and the variable can be used in the prompt?

Comment: `raw_input('{} eat {}'.format(K, F))`

Comment: .format or % will do

Comment: `raw_input(K + ' eat ' + F)` will also work

Comment: Andrew, make yourself a favour: do not learn Python2, learn Python3 instead.

Comment: Thank you for  everyone.  @gboffi，I use python 2.7.14 on AWS Instance. Thank you , I will  learn Python 3